# Tcl return vs. last evaluated in proc - internals

Tags: return, tcl, proc

When I write a proc in Tcl, which return value is actually the result of another proc I can do either of the following (see implicit example):

```
proc foo args {
...
...
bar $var1
}
```

Or I could do (see explicit example):

```
proc foo args {
...
...
return [ bar var1 ]
}
```

From an interface perspective, that is input vs. output, the two are identical.
Are they, internally?
Or is there some added benefit to implicit vs. explicit return?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tcl 8.6 you can inspect the bytecode to see how such procedures compare.

If we define a pair of implementations of 'sum' and then examine them using `tcl::unsupported::disassemble` we can see that using the `return` statement or not results in the same bytecode.

```
% proc sum_a {lhs rhs} {expr {$lhs + $rhs}}
% proc sum_b {lhs rhs} {return [expr {$lhs + $rhs}]}

% ::tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc sum_a
ByteCode 0x03C5E8E8, refCt 1, epoch 15, interp 0x01F68CE0 (epoch 15)
  Source "expr {$lhs + $rhs}"
  Cmds 1, src 18, inst 6, litObjs 0, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x03CC33C0, refCt 1, args 2, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, arg, "lhs"
      slot 1, scalar, arg, "rhs"
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-4, src 0-17
  Command 1: "expr {$lhs + $rhs}"
    (0) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "lhs"
    (2) loadScalar1 %v1     # var "rhs"
    (4) add 
    (5) done 

% ::tcl::unsupported::disassemble proc sum_b
ByteCode 0x03CAD140, refCt 1, epoch 15, interp 0x01F68CE0 (epoch 15)
  Source "return [expr {$lhs + $rhs}]"
  Cmds 2, src 27, inst 6, litObjs 0, aux 0, stkDepth 2, code/src 0.00
  Proc 0x03CC4B80, refCt 1, args 2, compiled locals 2
      slot 0, scalar, arg, "lhs"
      slot 1, scalar, arg, "rhs"
  Commands 2:
      1: pc 0-5, src 0-26        2: pc 0-4, src 8-25
  Command 1: "return [expr {$lhs + $rhs}]"
  Command 2: "expr {$lhs + $rhs}"
    (0) loadScalar1 %v0     # var "lhs"
    (2) loadScalar1 %v1     # var "rhs"
    (4) add 
    (5) done
```

The `return` statement is really just documenting that you *intended* to return this value and it is not just a side-effect. Using `return` is not necessary but in my opinion it is to be recommended.

Comment: I use Tcl 8.5. But I assume that it is the same.
Thanks!

Comment: `disassemble` is in 8.5 too. The bytecode is virtually the same; there's a few extra optimizations in 8.6, but they're minor.